# Juju - configuring a service by clicking on charm with stand-alone implementation - LXCa

Tags: juju

I brought up a local/stand-alone JUJU environment that creates LXCs for each service deployed.  What I notices is that I can't be redirected to the service configuration screen when clicking on the "charm" (Iam using a mac, OS X, Fusion) within the "juju-gui". This is the case with Wordpress, mysql, as well as a charm that I created.

Relationships, as it appears on juju-gui and defined via command line or juju-jui, appear to be only a "green line on the screen".  The charms that I loaded via local repository came up ok, and did not show green on juju-gui until completely up, but relationships (green line) do not appear to have any meaning other than graphical picture - no status.

Is this because I am in a stand-alone (local) dev environment?

I am running 14.04.

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two questions here...

**How to get to the services configuration screen from the Juju GUI**

There are two places, The inspector which shows up when you click on a service allows you to configure the charm, which will configure the service. If you want to get to a configuration UI for the deployed service, say in the case of Wordpress which has it's own admin panel. You will need to check the readme for the charm for this information. The unit's IP address can be found in the Inspector which was previously mentioned. You can also get this information from the command line by running `juju status`. There is some stuff in the pipeline to simplify this functionality in the GUI.

**Why is my relationship always green**

- Green - when the relationship hooks are running and/or completed successfully.
- Red - when a hook on either end has failed.

So it's likely that your environment relations are working as expected because the relation lines never turn red.